# Understanding Compact and Connected Sets

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, compactness, connectedness

I'm studying introductory complex analysis right now with Marsden's Basic Complex Analysis, and I'm stuck on understanding why the following are connected and/or compact (it's problem 1.4.15 on Marsden; the book has the solutions, but I don't really understand why there are what they are):

> 1) {$z$ | $1 \le |z| \le 2$} - Connected and Compact

Is this because the set is closed and bounded by $1$ and $3$? I also have no clue how to apply the "not connected" definition.. I need to show that this set is not a subset of some $2$ open sets, right? How do you generally go about doing that?

> 2) {$z$ such that $|z| \le 3$ and |Re $z$| $\ge 1$} - Compact, Not Connected

I don't quite see how this set is closed and bounded.. is it simply $1$ and $3$ as well?

> 3) {$z$ such that |Re $z$| $\le 1$} - Connected, Not Compact
>
> 4) {$z$ such that |Re $z$| $\ge 1$} - Neither

Completely lost on these.

Any help with me understanding why the answers are what they are would  be extremely helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

•By definition,  if it can be written as the disjoint union of open (hence also closed;  hence *clopen*) sets, the region isn't connected...

•Closed and bounded is equivalent to compact (by Heine-Borel)..

For (1), the region is an *annulus*( the region between two circles) ;  hence compact and connected  (it's all of one piece, and closed, since it includes its boundary, and bounded)

(2):  The region is two disjoint subsets of the closed disk of radius $3$.  It's not connected, since the union of these two regions, which are clopen, is the whole space. .  Easily seen to be closed and bounded...

(3):  This is a an infinite vertical strip of width $2$.  Clearly connected (one piece, intuitively) , since unbounded,  not compact...

(4):  This is the region outside the strip in (3), but including the boundary.  Clearly unbounded and with a big "hole" in it, it is the union of two clopen disjoint regions.  So neither..